# Unable to bundle searched files in Windows into a ZIP with their absolute path

Tags: windows, powershell, zip, access-denied, file-search

I wish to search for files or folders provided to `$itemsToInclude` under directory `C:\bea`
Once found it should add the found item [file or folder] to $zipFileName while persisting the folder structure.

Thus, if rt.jar is found in `C:\bea\dev\log\rt.jar` as well as `C:\bea\QA\log\rt.jar` my `C:\bea\package-dev.zip` should contain both like below:

```
- `C:\bea\dev\log\rt.jar`
- `C:\bea\QA\log\rt.jar`
```

Below is my attempt which fails with error `Access to the path 'C:\bea\package-dev.zip' is denied."` but my powershell can very well write to the `C:\bea\` folder. I dont expect to see any ACCESS DENIED error.

```
  $zipFileName = "C:\bea\package-dev.zip"
  cd "C:\bea"
  $itemsToInclude = "font.properties,rt.jar"
  Write-Host "itemsToInclude is- $itemsToInclude"
  $workspace = "C:\bea"
  if ($itemsToInclude -eq '*') {
  # Include all files, including files from subdirectories
  Write-Host "Include all files, including files from subdirectories"
  Get-ChildItem -Path $workspace -Recurse -File |
    Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFileName  -Update -Force
  } else {
  # Include specific files as per the comma-separated list
  Write-Host "Include specific files as per the comma-separated list"
  $pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
  $filesToInclude = Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File |
  Where-Object FullName -Match $pattern
  
  $filesToInclude | ForEach-Object {
    $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($workspace.Length)
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $zipFileName $relativePath
    $destinationFolder = Split-Path $destinationPath -Parent
    if (-not (Test-Path $destinationFolder)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationFolder | Out-Null
      }
      Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destinationPath -Force
    }
    Compress-Archive -Path $zipFileName -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Update
  }
```

Output:

```
itemsToInclude is- font.properties,rt.jar
Include specific files as per the comma-separated list
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\bea\package-dev.zip' is denied."
At C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:729 
char:30
+ ... ileStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Note: I m able to successfully create ZIP without the absolute path for files in the same directory using the below code:

```
  $zipFileName = "C:\bea\package-dev.zip"
  cd "C:\bea"
  $itemsToInclude = "font.properties,rt.jar"
  Write-Host "itemsToInclude is- $itemsToInclude"
  $workspace = "C:\bea"
  if ($itemsToInclude -eq '*') {
  # Include all files, including files from subdirectories
    Write-Host "Include all files, including files from subdirectories"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $workspace -Recurse -File |
      Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFileName  -Update -Force
     } else {
     # Include specific files as per the comma-separated list
     Write-Host "Include specific files as per the comma-separated list" 
       $pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
       Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File |
       Where-Object FullName -Match $pattern |
       Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Update
       }
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to determine why your code is failing, it might possible that the `Compress-Archive` is not correctly closing the zip stream or you have the zip opened while trying to run your code.

If you're able to install modules then using [`PSCompression`](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/New-ZipEntry.md#example-4-archive-all-files-in-a-specified-location) can simplify the task of adding zip entries to an existing zip archive for you. The module can be installed through the PowerShell Gallery using:

```bash
Install-Module PSCompression -Scope CurrentUser
```

Then the `else` peace of your code can be replaced using a similar logic as in the [example 4](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/New-ZipEntry.md#example-4-archive-all-files-in-a-specified-location) of the docs:

```bash
if (-not (Test-Path $zipFileName)) {
    $null = New-Item $zipFileName -ItemType File
}

Write-Host 'Include specific files as per the comma-separated list'
$pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
$filesToInclude = Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object FullName -Match $pattern

$filesToInclude | ForEach-Object {
    $newZipEntrySplat = @{
        EntryPath   = $_.FullName.Substring($workspace.Length)
        SourcePath  = $_.FullName
        Destination = $zipFileName
    }

    New-ZipEntry @newZipEntrySplat
}
```

Comment: @Ashar `New-ZipEntry` creates zip entries in an existing zip archive, there is no `-Update` because that is already assumed. You can read the linked docs if you want to know more.

Comment: this works. However, i will do a few tests before accepting the answer later in the day.

Comment: @Ashar did the answer solved your problem? If so, please consider accepting it